# How do I get a pfgplot figure to take up the whole page?

Tags: pgfplots

So, I'm making figures using `pgfplots` and I have a problem: They don't centre on the page well. I'd rather stick to `article` for ease of printing and so I can have multiple figure in the same document (If I have multiple spectra of the same compound, for example, it would be nice to have them all in one place).

However, when I compile it, the figure doesn't go all the way our to the right margin, which is quite annoying. How do I scale the figure to automatically use the whole page, but not have the axis lables go off the page or such?

I have a MWE that I used a tiny subset of my data in. I also pared it down (I normally use an external file for the data) and removed the labels and such to make it minimal):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5 in,landscape]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

%Graphics stuff here
\usepackage{pgfplots} %For graphing data
\pgfplotsset
  {
    compat                   = newest,
    every tick/.append style = thin,
    width= 0.95 \textwidth,
    height= 0.95\textheight
  }
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set thousands separator = }

%Science stuff here
\usepackage[]{siunitx} %Adds si units and others by name- See the manual.
\sisetup{mode = text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
      x dir               = reverse,
      xlabel              = Frequency (\si{\per\centi\metre}),
      title                 = Demo,
      xticklabel style      =   {rotate=270},
      yticklabels           = {},
    ]
\addplot[color = black, mark = none]
coordinates {
( 3.983730e+003, 9.824165e+001 )
( 3.984213e+003, 9.854189e+001 )
( 3.984695e+003, 9.890483e+001 )
( 3.985177e+003, 9.878275e+001 )
( 3.985659e+003, 9.859460e+001 )
( 3.986141e+003, 9.835152e+001 )
( 3.986623e+003, 9.794798e+001 )
( 3.987105e+003, 9.803477e+001 )
( 3.987587e+003, 9.864641e+001 )
( 3.988070e+003, 9.895673e+001 )
( 3.988552e+003, 9.910266e+001 )
( 3.989034e+003, 9.866454e+001 )
( 3.989516e+003, 9.837458e+001 )
( 3.989998e+003, 9.857204e+001 )
( 3.990480e+003, 9.883611e+001 )
( 3.990962e+003, 9.891921e+001 )
( 3.991444e+003, 9.846350e+001 )
( 3.991927e+003, 9.804715e+001 )
( 3.992409e+003, 9.815513e+001 )
( 3.992891e+003, 9.844558e+001 )
( 3.993373e+003, 9.842175e+001 )
( 3.993855e+003, 9.843822e+001 )
( 3.994337e+003, 9.828293e+001 )
( 3.994819e+003, 9.791080e+001 )
( 3.995301e+003, 9.774442e+001 )
( 3.995783e+003, 9.783126e+001 )
( 3.996266e+003, 9.788599e+001 )
( 3.996748e+003, 9.826096e+001 )
( 3.997230e+003, 9.857933e+001 )
( 3.997712e+003, 9.843895e+001 )
( 3.998194e+003, 9.839955e+001 )
( 3.998676e+003, 9.863584e+001 )
( 3.999158e+003, 9.872655e+001 )
( 3.999640e+003, 9.836100e+001 )
( 4.000123e+003, 9.836080e+001 )};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have `width=0.95\textwidth`. Reove `0.95`. Then it will span full text width. You may also make margins 0.

Comment: Some thoughts: You could make the data sit in a separate file instead of copy and paste so that it will help future iterations if any and use Tikz externalization to speed up for multiple figures and may be use `\includegraphics[]{}` to scale the figure to the fullest.

Comment: @texenthusiast I normally keep it as a external file, then import the data, however, I wanted a single file for the MWE to keep things easy to compile.

Comment: @Canageek just for info: one might use [filecontents](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/filecontents.pdf) package Ex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44573/15717

Comment: @texenthusiast I already had the way of setting it up with internal coordinates written (From before the chemistry saint Joseph Wright taught me how to make the data external), and I figured it wouldn't change anything with the answer just to use that. I'll keep it in mind for future though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps putting the `tikz` in a centered zero-width box is what you are looking for. EDITED to place `\centering` in a `\par`-ended group, thanks to suggestion by cfr.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5 in,landscape]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

%Graphics stuff here
\usepackage{pgfplots} %For graphing data
\pgfplotsset
  {
    compat                   = newest,
    every tick/.append style = thin,
    width= .95 \textwidth,
    height= .95\textheight
  }
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set thousands separator = }

%Science stuff here
\usepackage[]{siunitx} %Adds si units and others by name- See the manual.
\sisetup{mode = text}

\begin{document}
{\centering\makebox[0pt]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
      x dir               = reverse,
      xlabel              = Frequency (\si{\per\centi\metre}),
      title                 = Demo,
      xticklabel style      =   {rotate=270},
      yticklabels           = {},
    ]
\addplot[color = black, mark = none]
coordinates {
( 3.983730e+003, 9.824165e+001 )
( 3.984213e+003, 9.854189e+001 )
( 3.984695e+003, 9.890483e+001 )
( 3.985177e+003, 9.878275e+001 )
( 3.985659e+003, 9.859460e+001 )
( 3.986141e+003, 9.835152e+001 )
( 3.986623e+003, 9.794798e+001 )
( 3.987105e+003, 9.803477e+001 )
( 3.987587e+003, 9.864641e+001 )
( 3.988070e+003, 9.895673e+001 )
( 3.988552e+003, 9.910266e+001 )
( 3.989034e+003, 9.866454e+001 )
( 3.989516e+003, 9.837458e+001 )
( 3.989998e+003, 9.857204e+001 )
( 3.990480e+003, 9.883611e+001 )
( 3.990962e+003, 9.891921e+001 )
( 3.991444e+003, 9.846350e+001 )
( 3.991927e+003, 9.804715e+001 )
( 3.992409e+003, 9.815513e+001 )
( 3.992891e+003, 9.844558e+001 )
( 3.993373e+003, 9.842175e+001 )
( 3.993855e+003, 9.843822e+001 )
( 3.994337e+003, 9.828293e+001 )
( 3.994819e+003, 9.791080e+001 )
( 3.995301e+003, 9.774442e+001 )
( 3.995783e+003, 9.783126e+001 )
( 3.996266e+003, 9.788599e+001 )
( 3.996748e+003, 9.826096e+001 )
( 3.997230e+003, 9.857933e+001 )
( 3.997712e+003, 9.843895e+001 )
( 3.998194e+003, 9.839955e+001 )
( 3.998676e+003, 9.863584e+001 )
( 3.999158e+003, 9.872655e+001 )
( 3.999640e+003, 9.836100e+001 )
( 4.000123e+003, 9.836080e+001 )};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It can be made slightly bigger by changing

```
\pgfplotsset
  {
    compat                   = newest,
    every tick/.append style = thin,
    width= .95 \textwidth,
    height= .95\textheight
  }
```

and

```
\centering\makebox[0pt]{
```

to the following:

```
\pgfplotsset
  {
    compat                   = newest,
    every tick/.append style = thin,
    width= .99\textwidth,
    height=.99\textheight
  }
```

and

```
\centering\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-.99\textheight}{\smash{%
```

and adding 2 extra closing braces before the `\end{document}`.

[image]

Comment: (+1) But shouldn't `\centering` be grouped so it doesn't affect subsequent material?

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the reminder.  Edited per your suggestion.